# How to properly dispose of image bitmap after emailing a screenshot?

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap

New to android. I'm taking a screen shot of my activity, and emailing it out. Here's my process:

```
 public void emailScreenShot()  {

    //get bitmap of activity
    View v = DeSlip.this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(),
            v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    v.draw(canvas);

    //save bitmap externally
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file = new File(path, AName + "vs" + BName+ ".JPEG");
    Uri pngUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    FileOutputStream fos;

    //compress
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("BoutSlip", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("BoutSlip", e.getMessage(), e);
    }


    //email intent
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("image/png");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send image using:"));

}
```

This works well, and gets my stuff out into the internet. My question is regarding using the external storage  (I have permission in manifest). Is there some process I should be doing in order to remove or delete this bitmap after I have finished using it before I close? Or will the android memory management automatically take care of that with other stack items?

My gut says no, however you do want the bitmap around long enough to email (but I wasn't seeing it on the gallery app, so I know it's not available there).

Comment: you can Recycle the bitmap and set to null in onActivityResult() if you want to do so. i.e if (myBitmap != null) {
    myBitmap.recycle();
    myBitmap = null;
}